# Changing svg shape color on checkbox click

Tags: html, css, svg, checkbox

I would like to change the fill color of an svg shape when a checkbox is clicked. I have this working, however if I wrap the checkbox input in a div tag it no longer works.

```css
#circles {
  fill: #00ffff;
}

#circ-toggle .toggler:checked~#circles .circ1 {
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="circ-toggle" class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" class="toggler">
  <label for="toggle-1" class="btn-toggle">Change Color</label>
</div>

<div id="circles">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 30">
        <g>
            <circle class="circ1" cx="1" cy="1" r="1" />
            <circle class="circ2" cx="3" cy="1" r="1" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your design can tolerate this change, then your current css will work:

Notice that I have moved the closing tag for `<div id="circ-toggle" class="toggle">` to the end of your css so that it encapsulates `<div id="circles">`. Doing this creates a sibling relationship between the `checkbox` and `<div id="circles">`. Now the [general sibling combinator (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)  can reach the desired element.

You could of course use javascript to easily accomplish this but it looks like you want a css-only answer.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('toggle-1')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    alert('checked');
  } else {
    alert('not checked');
  }
})
```

```css
#circles {
  fill: #00ffff;
}

.gray {
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="circ-toggle" class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" class="toggler">
  <label for="toggle-1" class="btn-toggle">Change Color</label>
</div>
<div id="circles">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 30">
        <g>
            <circle class="circ1" cx="1" cy="1" r="1" />
            <circle class="circ2" cx="3" cy="1" r="1" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is a javascript method:

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('toggle-1');
const circle = document.querySelector("#circles > svg > g > circle.circ1");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    circle.classList.add("gray");
  } else {
    circle.classList.remove("gray");
  }
})
```

```css
#circles {
  fill: #00ffff;
}

.gray {
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="circ-toggle" class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" class="toggler">
  <label for="toggle-1" class="btn-toggle">Change Color</label>
</div>
<div id="circles">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 30">
        <g>
            <circle class="circ1" cx="1" cy="1" r="1" />
            <circle class="circ2" cx="3" cy="1" r="1" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe that will work with my current design. Is there another way with CSS, or would doing this in javascript be an alternative?

Comment: @Galgenstrick - Yes. As I mentioned in my original answer this can be accomplished using javascript. See the edited answer. The second snippet puts your html back to original and uses JS to either add or remove a class (`.gray`) based on the checked status.

Comment: I integrated the JavaScript you provided into my design and it works great, thank you!